# If $A,B,$ and $C$ are finite abelian groups with $A\oplus C \cong B \oplus C$, then $A \cong B$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm trying to do the following exercise from Rotman's book, An Introduction to Theory of Groups.

> **6.10** i) If $A,B,$ and $C$ are finite abelian groups with $A\oplus C \cong B \oplus C$, then $A \cong B$.

Hint: Use Exercise **6.9**.

Exercise **6.9** says that:

> **6.9** If $G$ and $H$ are finite abelian groups then
> $$U_p(n,G\oplus H)=U_p(n,G)+U_n(p,H)$$
> for all primes $p$ and $n \geq 0$.

I found the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227812/the-cancellation-property-for-finite-abelian-groups) solution on this site, but I think it is not a duplicate, as the proposed solution is different.

The problem is that $U_p(n,G)$ is only defined for $p-$primary group, that is:

> **Definition** (page 131): If $G$ is a $p-$primary abelian group and $n \geq 0$, then
> $$U_p(n,G)=d(p^nG/p^{n+1}G)-d(p^{n+1}G/p^{n+2}G),$$
> where $d(H)$ is the dimension of $H$ as considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if $pH=\{0\}$ for some prime $p$.

**My attempt:** I started considering $A, B$, and $C$ $p-$primary and I did Exercise 6.9. After that, I applied this result to my problem, getting
$$U_p(n,A)+U_p(n,C)=U_p(n,A\oplus C)=U_p(n,B\oplus C)=U_p(n,B)+U_p(n,C)$$
which implies that
$$U_p(n,A)=U_p(n,B) \hbox{ for all } n \geq 0. \tag{$\star$}$$
Now, Corollary $6.12$ ensures that if $G$ and $H$ are finite $p-$primary abelian groups, then $G \cong H$ if, and only if, $U_p(n,G)=U_p(n,H)$ for all $n \geq 0$. Therefore, from $(\star)$ we obtain that $A \cong B$.

Comment: See also other duplicates here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102560/if-a-oplus-b-cong-a-oplus-c-then-b-cong-c?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think they are duplicates, since the proposed solutions are different.

Comment: They prove your title claim with the theorem on finitely generated abelian groups, so that's what you want, don't you?

Comment: Not exactly, the approaches are different.

Comment: The Exercise clearly says to use other tools.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that should be finite abelian groups, right? Or is it true even in the finitely generated case too?

Comment: Well, the "other tools" are not so different. Yes, it is even true in the finitely generated case, see the "Theorem on finitely generated abelian groups". Of course, finite abelian is a special case.

Comment: I agree. It feels like a recast of the same ideas to me.

Comment: TIL! I guess that makes sense, finite generation is a pretty structured setting so I can the result generalizing.